# How can I change the body of template in meteor with a html on another template?

Tags: javascript, jquery, meteor, d3.js, c3.js

I'm trying to generate many graph on a template, my first graph is default , I'd like when I click on a zone I generate another graph who exist in a another template. How can I do that ?

I try to return my template with my other grahp.

```
Template.test.events({'click .zone' : function (e){
  console.log("J'ai cliqué sur le template Test ... on va essayer d'ouvrir une pop up");
  e.preventDefault();
  //$('#animalsModal').modal('show');
  return {template: Template[createGraph]};
}});
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use Template.dynamic for this purpose.

**//html**

```
<template name="graphDisplayer">
{{> Template.dynamic template=helperToGetDynamicTemplate}}
</template>
```

**//JS**

```
Template.graphDisplayer.onCreated(function(){
  this.templateNameOfGraph = new ReactiveVar('yourDefaultTemplate');
});

Template.graphDisplayer.events({
  'click .zone':function(e,t) {
    t.templateNameOfGraph.set('yourOtherTemplate');
  }
});

Template.graphDisplayer.helpers({
  helperToGetDynamicTemplate:function(){
    return Template.instance().templateNameOfGraph.get();
  }
});
```

Comment: When I do this code my data of my first graph change. I use jquery specify my div. Thank you!